# How to get exact roots of this polynomial?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, polynomials

The equation $$ 64x^7 -112x^5 -8x^4 +56x^3 +8x^2 -7x - 1 = 0 $$
has seven solutions $x = 1$, $x = -\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $x = \cos \dfrac{2n\pi}{11}$, where $n$ runs from $1$ to $5$.  With `NSolve`, I tried

```
NSolve[64 x^7 - 112 x^5 - 8 x^4 + 56 x^3 + 8 x^2 - 7 x - 1 == 0, x, Reals]
```

and I get

```
{{x -> -0.959493}, {x -> -0.654861}, {x -> -0.5}, {x -> -0.142315}, \
{x -> 0.415415}, {x -> 0.841254}, {x -> 1.}}
```

With `Solve`, I tried

```
{{x -> -(1/2)}, {x -> 1}, 
  {x -> Root[1 + 6 #1 - 12 #1^2 - 32 #1^3 + 16 #1^4 + 32 #1^5 &, 1]}, 
  {x -> Root[1 + 6 #1 - 12 #1^2 - 32 #1^3 + 16 #1^4 + 32 #1^5 &, 2]}, 
  {x -> Root[1 + 6 #1 - 12 #1^2 - 32 #1^3 + 16 #1^4 + 32 #1^5 &, 3]}, 
  {x -> Root[1 + 6 #1 - 12 #1^2 - 32 #1^3 + 16 #1^4 + 32 #1^5 &, 4]}, 
  {x -> Root[1 + 6 #1 - 12 #1^2 - 32 #1^3 + 16 #1^4 + 32 #1^5 &, 5]}}
```

How to get exact solutions of the given equation?

Comment: A first step forward is `Solve[Factor[64 x^7 - 112 x^5 - 8 x^4 + 56 x^3 + 8 x^2 - 7 x - 1] == 
  0, x]`.

Comment: @b.gates And the next two steps are to let $x\to z/2$ to clear out powers of $2$ and then to take the big factor, $p(z)=1+3 z-3 z^2-4 z^3+z^4+z^5$ and symmetrize it via $p(z+1/z)z^5$: the primitive eleventh roots of unity pop right out.

Comment: @minthao: Those roots *are* exact. What you seem to mean, then, is that you wish to identify *some* of the roots with *some* of the roots of *another* (unspecified) polynomial (which is how those cosines are defined).

Comment: @whuber Brilliant !

Comment: @whuber Why don't you switch your comment to another answer ?

Comment: @Artes Thank you for the suggestion. I posted them as comments because I don't think they actually answer the question: they require one to anticipate that the root really is a trigonometric value and will not work in general.

Comment: @whuber I think it can be elaborated to quite a nice answer. With a standard transform `x->(z + 1/z)/2` one needn't assume anything more than has been assumed in the question. This special transformation (quite obvious since all roots satisfy $1 \geq x_{k} \geq -1$) makes a new polynomial being a product of cyclotomic ones.

Comment: What a great question!  Related:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626829/how-to-tell-if-a-polynomial-has-exact-trigonometric-roots

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since we ask if the numbers  $\;x_n = \cos(\frac{2n\pi}{11})\;$ are the actual roots of the polynomial :

```
p[x_] := 64 x^7 - 112 x^5 - 8 x^4 + 56 x^3 + 8 x^2 - 7 x - 1
```

any numerical approach cannot be sufficient and in order to prove the statement  we should **proceed with a symbolic approach**. Nevertheless  `NSolve`  may guarantee that all the roots could be represented in terms of values of trigonometrical functions like `Sin` or `Cos` for real arguments since we have :

```
And @@ ( -1 <= x <= 1 /. NSolve[ p[x] == 0, x] )
```

> ```
> True
> ```

The five of the roots are represented in terms of the `Root` objects, and only two of them have been rewritten by built-in rewrite rules as rational numbers :

```
r = List @@ Roots[64 x^7 - 112 x^5 - 8 x^4 + 56 x^3 + 8 x^2 - 7 x - 1 == 0, x][[All, 2]];
r[[5 ;;]]
```

> ```
> { Root[1 + 6 #1 - 12 #1^2 - 32 #1^3 + 16 #1^4 + 32 #1^5 &, 5], -(1/2), 1}
> ```

Now we can  experss `r[[;;5]]` in terms of `Cos` (it is possible as we have shown above), we can do it this way :

```
ArcCos @ r[[;; 5]] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> { 10π/11, 8π/11, 6 π/11, 4π/11, 2π/11}
> ```

We might also use `ArcSin` as well. Let`s verify if they are equal :

```
Table[ Root[1 + 6 #1 - 12 #1^2 - 32 #1^3 + 16 #1^4 + 32 #1^5 &, k] - Cos[2(6 - k)π/11],
       {k, 5}] // RootReduce
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

Well,  indeed these are the roots of the polynomial $p(x)$. One observes that `FullSimplify` cannot reduce the above `Table` with the standard built-in rewrite rules unless one uses e.g. `Table[ Root[...] - Cos[...], {k,5}]// FullSimplify[#, TransformationFunctions -> RootReduce]&`.

Another way which might be helpful in more involved cases would be e.g. mapping `PossibleZeroQ`, however we have to remember that `PossibleZeroQ` provides a quick but **not always accurate test**.

### Edit

Since all the roots can be represented as `Sin` or `Cos` for real arguments, it would be a good idea to explain what is so specific behind the polynomial `p[x]`. We can reach a general view working with a transformation pointed out by whuber in the [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17269/how-to-get-exact-roots-of-this-polynomial#comment51066_17269).

```
g[z_] := (p[x] /. x -> (z + 1/z)/2) 2 z^Exponent[p[x], x]
g[z] // Factor
```

> ```
> (-1 + z)^2 (1 + z + z^2) (1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + z^5 + z^6 + z^7 + z^8 + z^9 + z^10)
> ```

All the roots of `g[z]` are roots of unity :

```
And @@ RootOfUnityQ[ List @@ Roots[ g[z] == 0, z][[All, 2]] ]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

moreover all the polynomial factors of `g[z]` are [cyclotomic polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclotomicPolynomial.html), respectively $C^{2}_{1}(z)$, $C_{3}(z)$ and $C_{11}(z)$ (see [`Cyclotomic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cyclotomic.html?q=Cyclotomic&lang=en)), so we have :

```
Times @@ (Cyclotomic[#, z] & /@ {1, 1, 3, 11}) == g[z] // Factor
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Following in reverse direction we would generate more polynomials with the roots expressible in terms of $\sin$ or $\cos$ functions on rational multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: +1 Example of another way: the output of `MinimalPolynomial[
 Root[1 + 6 #1 - 12 #1^2 - 32 #1^3 + 16 #1^4 + 32 #1^5 &, 1] - 
  Cos[10 \[Pi]/11]]` is `#1 &`.

Answer (score 10):

```
Element[Cos[Pi/11], Algebraics]
(*True*)    

ExpToTrig /@ Factor[-1 - 7 x + 8 x^2 + 56 x^3 - 8 x^4 - 112 x^5 + 64 x^7, Extension -> Cos[Pi/11]]
(*Or ComplexExpand*)

(*(-1+x) (1+2 x) (-2 x-2 Cos[π/11]) (2 x-2 Cos[(2 π)/11]) (2 x-2 Sin[(3 π)/22]) (-2 x-2 Sin[(5 π)/22]) (1+2 x-2 Cos[π/11]+2 Cos[(2 π)/11]+2 Sin[(3 π)/22]-2 Sin[(5 π)/22])*)

x /. Solve[% == 0, x]

(*{-(1/2), 1, -Cos[π/11], Cos[(2 π)/11], Sin[(3 π)/22], -Sin[(5 π)/22], 
 1/2 (-1 + 2 Cos[π/11] - 2 Cos[(2 π)/11] - 2 Sin[(3 π)/22] + 2 Sin[(5 π)/22])}*)
```

Answer (score 6):

Okay, sometimes you get so involved in an idea that you don't realize how foolish it is.  I was fooled or seduced by the simplicity of the Chebyshev expansion.  Basically, my original answer was a complicated way to do this:

```
cosEq = 64 x^7 - 112 x^5 - 8 x^4 + 56 x^3 + 8 x^2 - 7 x - 1 /. x -> Cos[Pi t] //TrigToExp;
t /. Solve[cosEq == 0 && 0 <= t <= 1, t]
(*  {0, 0, 2/11, 4/11, 6/11, 2/3, 8/11, 10/11}  *)
```

The fundamental, simple idea is that if you think the solutions can be expressed in terms of cosine, then replacing the variable by cosine is a natural thing to try.  If the angles are rational multiples of `Pi`, then `x -> Cos[Pi t]` will probably be a convenient substitution for determining which multiples.

Note that some cosines are automatically converted to sines by *Mathematica*.

```
Cos[Pi %]
(*  {1, 1, Cos[(2 π)/11], Sin[(3 π)/22], -Sin[π/22], -(1/2), -Sin[(5 π)/22], -Cos[π/11]}  *)
```

The simple root `x == 1` (or `t == 0`) appears twice because `Cos[Pi t] == 1` has a double root.

If one would like to have unique solutions in terms of cosines for output-formatting purposes, then one could do something like

```
HoldForm[Cos[t Pi]] /. DeleteDuplicates@ Solve[TrigToExp[cosEq] == 0 && 0 <= t <= 1];
% /. HoldForm[x_?NumberQ] :> HoldForm[Evaluate@ x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Original answer**

Basically I converted the OP's polynomial to

```
-ChebyshevT[4, x] + ChebyshevT[7, x]
```

which can be replaced by

```
-Cos[4 Pi t] + Cos[7 Pi t]
```

whose roots are easy to find by hand.  To use *Mathematica* to get the solutions, I had to use `TrigToExp`, as I did above.  See edit history for full discussion.

Answer (score 4):

This is too big for a comment, so I am writing it here. I am not sure if there is a trick to make `Solve` return the exact solution $x =\cos\dfrac{2 n\pi} {11}$. But for sure, whether `Solve` or `NSolve`, these functions tend to give pretty accurate solutions for such straightforward polynomials.

**Proof of practical exactness**

Solve the equation and through the two rational roots $\{1,-0.5\}$

```
res = Select[(Solve[64 x^7 - 112 x^5 - 8 x^4 + 56 x^3 + 8 x^2 - 7 x - 1 == 0, x, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 200] // N)[[All, 1,2]],
    (# != -0.5 && # != 1.) &] // Sort;
```

The expected real roots

```
pred = N[Cos[2 # Pi/11], 200] & /@ Range[5] // Sort;
```

Now difference between expected and obtained results

```
res - pred
```

> > {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}

Answer (score 4):

algebraic demonstration of the forward problem:

```
Simplify[Collect[ 
  ExpandAll[64 (x + 1/2) Product[ x - Cos[2 n π/11], {n, 0, 5} ]] , {x}  ,
        (  TrigReduce[#] /.  
         Sin[(5π)/22] -> 
            1/2 - (Cos[π/11] - Cos[(2π)/11] +
                   Sin[π/22] - Sin[(3π)/22]) ) &]]
```

> $-1 - 7 x + 8 x^2 + 56 x^3 - 8 x^4 - 112 x^5 + 64 x^7$

Not quite a proof as I haven't proved that identity I manualy applied.