# Most efficient way to determine conclusively whether an algebraic number is zero

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Let `x` be an algebraic number of unspecified degree, expressed using arithmetic, rational powers, and <strike>algebraic integers</strike> (edit: `Root[...]` constructs). I would like to test conclusively whether it is zero.

I don't know whether any of the following are guaranteed to work:

```
x==0
Simplify[x]==0
FullSimplify[x]==0
PossibleZeroQ[x,Method->"ExactAlgebraics"]
```

The following should work, but seems unlikely to be efficient:

```
MinimalPolynomial[x][y]===y
```

I don't want to use numerical approximation unless the answer is guaranteed to be correct.

Do any of the first four lines above guarantee a correct answer?

What is the best way to perform this test in Mathematica?

Comment: Numeric approximation via N[algnum,digits] is guaranteed in the sense that it can tell you if a number is not zero. If it gives a result with no accuracy (because it is dealing with a zero or did not have sufficient precision to determine otherwise) then the test is inconclusive. So there's no incorrect case. Maybe then a next step would be your PossibleZeroQ route.

Comment: @Daniel I was always wondering, how accurate is Mathematica's precision tracking?  I.e. if it gives me a result with a `Precision` of 10, does that *guarantee* that at least 10 digits are correct (assuming that there are no bugs in the software), or should I take it only as a guideline (an estimate)?

Comment: @Szabolcs it uses first-order error propagation assuming uncorrelated errors, as in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16793/16803#16803) answer (in which I need to fix a mistake; *Mathematica*'s implementation is actually fully correct to first order but I am not comparing like with like in my example). So, no, it isn't in any sense a *guarantee*, but rather an *estimate*--about as good as you'll get elsewhere, but by no means rigorous. For values with very little precision it'll probably be fairly inaccurate.

Comment: @Szabolcs Part I It depends on the computations being done. For addition/subtraction it is full accurate up to the granularity with which precision is recorded (machine double prec). For multiplication/division/powering it is a first order error model. Still very good in a sense, if you have more digits than the granularity of the precision field, insofar as second order error will be at most comparable to the "error error" from having discrete gradations in the precision. For other computations it will depend on method used both to compute and to estimate error.

Comment: @Szabolcs Part II More detail can be found in "Precise numerical computation" by Sofroniou and Spaletta. J. Log. Algebr. Program. 64(1): 113-134 (2005)

Comment: I found that the in some examples I encountered, the `MinimalPolynomial` approach was both faster and more reliable than any other method. The `PossibleZeroQ` often claimed to not have a reliable answer at first run. There was no such message when I re-executed the line, but I'm not sure whether that's due to the message being suppressed or whether it somehow got a reliable answer that time. I must say that I consider the handling of [algebraic numbers in Sage](http://sagemath.org/doc/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/qqbar.html) to be much more user-friendly, but that's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes the only conclusive way of the four methods considered in the question can be `PossibleZeroQ[ x, Method->"ExactAlgebraics"]`, it appears to be the most efficient as well. Dealing with explicitly algebraic numbers  in almost all tests it is faster than `FullSimplify`. The main reason for this issue seems to be that `FullSimplify` is assumed to work with special functions, transcendental numbers and so on, thus there is a broader range of possible transformations while the option `Method->"ExactAlgebraics"` restricts to specific polynomial (algebraic) transformations. Moreover `FullSimplify` being able to transform given expressions involes drawbacks with respect to efficiency comparing it to `PossibleZeroQ` only performing tests yielding  two values : `True` or `False`.

**Explicit algebraic numbers**

At first we need at least a few algebraic numbers i.e. roots of univariate non-zero polynomials with rational coefficients which are not explictly zero. We can provide a desired list of algebraic numbers using `RootReduce` to any nested radicals.

```
{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6} = 
{
 (Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[6] + 3)/Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[6]] - 1 - Sqrt[3], 

 (-72 (1 - I Sqrt[3]))^(1/4) - 3 - I Sqrt[3], 

 Root[1 + #1^4 &, 4]
 - ((7 - 2I)/(1 + I Sqrt[2]) + (4 + 14I)/(Sqrt[2] + 2I) - 8 + 2I)^(1/4),

 ((1 - 5 I)/(1 + I) - 5 (1 + 2 I)/(2 - I) + 2)^(1/3) - Root[16 - 4 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 3],

 ((-2 + 2 Sqrt[3] I)/(2 + I Sqrt[5]) - 5 (Sqrt[3] + I)/(2 Sqrt[5] + 5 I))^(1/4) 
 - Root[4 + 2 #1^4 + #1^8 &, 8],

 - Root[ 65536 + 16384 #1^2 - 1024 #1^6 - 256 #1^8 - 64 #1^10 + 4 #1^14 + #1^16 &, 15] 
 + (512 (1 - I Sqrt[3]))^(1/10) };
```

We do not test the first two ways (i.e. `x == 0` and `Simplify[x] == 0`) since they certainly cannot guarantee that an algebraic number is zero e.g. we can check it with `x == x1`. One can see that neither `x1 == 0` nor `Simplify[x1] == 0`  yield any constructive answers. While the other two methods work well.

Let's define a testing function :

```
rT[x_] := 
  Module[{a, b},
          a = AbsoluteTiming[ PossibleZeroQ[x, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]];
          b = AbsoluteTiming[ FullSimplify[x] == 0];
          If[ Last[a] ~ And ~ Last[b], First[a]/First[b]] ]
```

and it yields :

```
rT /@ {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6} // Column
```

> ```
> 0.01111
> 0.1364
> 0.455
> 0.1667
> 1.222
> 0.48927
> ```

when we quit the kernel and try a twin function (reveresd the order of evaluation) :

```
rT1[x_] := 
  Module[{a, b},
          b = AbsoluteTiming[ FullSimplify[x] == 0]; 
          a = AbsoluteTiming[ PossibleZeroQ[x, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]];
          If[ Last[a] ~ And ~Last[b], First[a]/First[b]] ]
```

we can see even much better ratios :

```
rT1 /@ {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6} // Column
```

> ```
> 0.00448
> 0.0435
> 0.364
> 0.0769
> 0.667
> 0.41071
> ```

**Non-explicit algebraics**

Let's consider another example (see [How to get exact roots of this polynomial ?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17269/how-to-get-exact-roots-of-this-polynomial/17275#17275)) where the numbers `Cos[2 (6 - k) π/11]` for `k ∈ Range[5]` are not explicitely algebraic, but `Mathematica` simply decides they are indeed algebraic.

```
And @@ FullSimplify @ Table[ Cos[2 (6 - k) π/11] ∈ Algebraics, {k, 5}]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

```
And @@ ( PossibleZeroQ[#, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]& /@ 
         Table[ Root[1 + 6 #1 - 12 #1^2 - 32 #1^3 + 16 #1^4 + 32 #1^5 &, k] -
                Cos[2 (6 - k) π/11],  {k, 5}])
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

however `FullSimplify[Table[...]]` is not  sufficient here even though we could prove that numbers are zero with `RootReduce`. One should point out that using options in `FullSimplify` we could  prove as well that the above algebraics are zeros but in general it is difficult to guess which  option (what `ComplexityFunction` or `TransformationFunctions`) can be helpful.

Let's consider the last example :

```
xa = RootSum[ 3 - 2 #1 + #1^7 &, (PolyGamma[0, -#1] #1)/(-2 + 7 #1^6) &];
xb = RootSum[2 + 5 #1 + 21 #1^2 + 35 #1^3 + 35 #1^4 + 21 #1^5 + 7 #1^6 + #1^7 &, 
                (PolyGamma[0, -#1] + PolyGamma[0, -#1] #1)/(5 + 42 #1 + 105 #1^2 
                  + 140 #1^3 + 105 #1^4 + 42 #1^5 + 7 #1^6) &];
x = xa - xb;
```

We can't prove with `Mathematica` whether `xa` and `xb` are algebraic numbers.

```
PossibleZeroQ[ x1, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]
```

> ```
>  PossibleZeroQ::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity 
> RootSum[3-2 #1+#1^7&,(PolyGamma[0,-#1] #1)/(-2+7 Power[<<2>>])&] - RootSum[2+5 #1+...])&]
>  is equal to zero. Assuming it is. >>
>
>   True
> ```

We can see that `PossibleZeroQ` is not powerful enough to yield a definitive answer but `FullSimplify` cannot do it at all.
 Nonetheless one can prove that `x1` is indeed `0`.

To sum up  `PossibleZeroQ[ x, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]` is clearly faster than `FullSimplify` as well as more connvenient and universal in tests. However the latter can simplify expressions while the former one cannot.

Comment: Help > Documentation > PossibleZeroQ > Details item 2: "With the setting Method->"ExactAlgebraics", PossibleZeroQ will use exact guaranteed methods in the case of explicit algebraic numbers." Your example with the cosine terms does not give explicit algebraic numbers. Ergo no foul was committed by `PossibleZeroQ`. The last erxample is probably further removed from algebraics in the sense that quite possibly the input cannot be expressed as such even in theory.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau One can easily verify that `Cos[2(6 - k)π/11]` for `k` in `{1,2,3,4,5}` are algebraic numbers even though they are not explicit. `x1` is `0` while the first `RootSum` and the second one probably are not algebraic numbers.

Comment: Yes, those are (nonexplicit) algebraic numbers. I think I had implicitly implied that. (I guess I could have explicitly explied it.) Anyway, does not change the situation: the ExactAlgebraics method setting will be of no avail to PZQ.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau `PossibleZeroQ[ x1, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]` works well here, I was mislead because it is not `Listable` using it this way `Table[...]// PossibleZeroQ[#, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"] &`. Thanks for drawing my attention to it. I have to update my answer.

Comment: I'm surprised. Of course it's always a pleasant surprise when something works more generally than what's documented.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear that the numbers I am interested in are explicitly algebraic. @DanielLichtblau my difficulty was that I didn't understand that sentence in the documentation, but this discussion has made it clear to me. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @TobiasHagge Later I will edit my answer to include some testing. But so far I can say that `PossibleZeroQ[ x1, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]` is always faster than `FullSimplify` even with restriction to algebraic numbers. Mainly because the former is assumed to work with algebraic numbers only while the latter must tackle general expressions involving special functions, transcendentals and so on.

Comment: In addition to the issues @Artes notes re FullSimplify, there is the fact that it may try several different operations. This carries the drawback of taking time, and also of allowing for the possibility that it will find its way into a "local" simplification that is suboptimal.