# How to check an algebraic number for membership in a list

Tags: functions, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

I need to check an algebraic number for membership in a list of algebraic numbers. The numbers can be expressed in different forms (combinations of radicals, `Root` objects, trig functions), but the check should be exact. Now I use the following code:

```
ContainsAlgebraicQ[list_, a_] := 
  MatchQ[Intersection[ list, {a}, SameTest -> (MinimalPolynomial[#1 - #2] === (#&) &)], {_}]
```

but in some cases evaluation of `MinimalPolynomial` takes significant time, although I only want to check the difference for zero. Is there a better approach for my task?

Comment: `PossibleZeroQ` might be of some help.

Comment: Consider `MemberQ[{Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3], Sin[\[Pi]/5], GoldenRatio, Root[#^3 - 2 &, 1]}, x_ /; RootReduce[x - 2^(1/3)] == 0]`...

Comment: I'd do this with `PossibleZeroQ[ # - a, "ExactAlgebraics"]@list`, or just `MemberQ[PossibleZeroQ[ #, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]& @ list, True]`.  This post is closely related:  [Most efficient way to determine conclusively whether an algebraic number is zero](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18381/most-efficient-way-to-determine-conclusively-whether-an-algebraic-number-is-zero/18390#18390)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PossibleZeroQ[ #, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]` provides the most efficient and exact test whether two algebraics are equal, (see e.g.  [Most efficient way to determine conclusively whether an algebraic number is zero](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18381/most-efficient-way-to-determine-conclusively-whether-an-algebraic-number-is-zero/18390#18390) for some benchmarks). It is `Listable` so we can define the following function:

```
ContainsAlgebraicQ[list_, a_] := 
    MemberQ[PossibleZeroQ[list - a, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"], True]
```

E.g. check if `1 + Sqrt[3]` is an element of

```
list = { Root[4 + 2 #1^4 + #1^8 &, 8], 
         (Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[6] + 3)/Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[6]],
         ((7 - 2 I)/(1 + I Sqrt[2]) + (4 + 14 I)/(Sqrt[2] + 2 I) - 8 + 2 I)^(1/4) };

ContainsAlgebraicQ[ list, 1 + Sqrt[3]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

but

```
ContainsAlgebraicQ[ list, Root[4 + 2 #1^4 + #1^8 &, 7]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

and of course

```
ContainsAlgebraicQ[ list, Root[4 + 2 #1^4 + #1^8 &, 8]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Based on my observations of how this code works, I assume that trig functions of rational multiples of `π` are not considered explicit algebraics by _Mathematica_. So I added a step that invokes `RootReduce` on expressions containing any trig functions before passing them to `PossibleZeroQ`. Please let me know if you are aware of a better approach.

Comment: I think you need not to use `RootReduce` before `PossibleZeroQ`. Though Daniel Lichtblau has been surprised that `PossibleZeroQ[ #, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]&` worked for non-explicit algebraics. But for a more reliable approach it might be safer.

Answer (score 1):

If `list` has sufficiently many repeated subexpressions, it becomes efficient to convert the elements to explicit algebraic numbers in a common number field.

```
list=ToNumberField[list,All]
```

Performance testing suggests that `ToNumberField` memoizes evaluations of subexpressions. Evaluation is fast when the input is an algebraic combination of previously evaluated subexpressions.

```
(* all elements of list must be explicit algebraic numbers in a common number field *)
ContainsAlgebraicQ[{},a_,extension_]= False
ContainsAlgebraicQ[list_,a_,extension_]:=
  Quiet[MemberQ[list,ToNumberField[a,AlgebraicNumberPolynomial[list[[1]]]]]]
```

Here, `Quiet` suppresses a message that occurs when `a` is not in the number field generated by `extension`. I'm not sure what performance is like in this case; your application may allow better options for choice of `extension`.