# How to make Mathematica try harder to perform symbolic comparisons?

Tags: numerics, symbolic

(I suspect this question is a duplicate, but I didn't find a sufficiently similar question with an answer to it.)

I'm having trouble with comparisons of symbolic `Reals` that are equal, but which Mathematica has trouble recognising them as equal, apparently because it uses `N` to compare these (apparently after some simple symbolic manipulation). Typically these issues creep up in conditions like one (greatly simplified) below:

```
x > y /. {x -> Sqrt[(2 - Sqrt[3])^2 + (-3 + 2*Sqrt[3])^2], y -> 4 - 2*Sqrt[3]}
```

> N::meprec: "Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating -4+2\ Sqrt[3]+Sqrt[(2-Sqrt[3])^2+(-3+2 Sqrt[3])^2]."
>
> Sqrt[(2 - Sqrt[3])^2 + (-3 + 2*Sqrt[3])^2] > 4 - 2*Sqrt[3]

This is in no way undocumented feature; it is discussed under Possible Issues section of `$MaxExtraPrecision`.

What I really want is Mathematica to try a bit harder on solving these (in)equalities numerically in a block of code. How do I accomplish this? As a workaround for specific problem above, this does work (while `Simplify` on inequality part doesn't):

```
x > y /. Simplify @ {x -> Sqrt[(2 - Sqrt[3])^2 + (-3 + 2*Sqrt[3])^2], y -> 4 - 2*Sqrt[3]}
```

> False

I would be happy to see a solution that could wrap up around a block of code, and which could possibly work also on non-algebraics that `FullSimplify` can handle.

**EDIT:**

To clarify my question: I want first example to evaluate like the expression below, and in general `Greater` to evaluate for `NumericQ` argument list similarly inside a code block where I want this feature to be used:

```
  Simplify[Sqrt[(2 - Sqrt[3])^2 + (-3 + 2*Sqrt[3])^2]] > Simplify[4 - 2*Sqrt[3]]
```

> False

Comment: @Artes My specific question here is how to make comparisons work this way; typically this stuff creeps up in my case in complicated equation systems Mathematica has generated itself.

Comment: @Artes `N` appears only in the error message, not in my code. This is exactly the inconvenience I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: I do not know if following will work for you or not, but myself, I like to keep everything in `MachinePrecision` only to be able to compare things with Matlab and Fortran when I want to. You can force all computation to be in `MachinePrecision` by putting this at the top of the notebook or in your init.m `$MinPrecision = $MachinePrecision; $MaxPrecision = $MachinePrecision;` Now your example runs with no warnings: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QqbiQ.png) again, do not know if this is what you want, or this will work for what you are doing.

Comment: @Nasser Not a bad workaround for applications where minuscule differences are known not to matter; but I guess it turns comparison into machine-precision numeric operation? I'd wish to make `Less` try a bit more in symbolic manner, and return unevaluated if it's indecisive, instead of providing a possibly wrong result through limited-precision numeric evaluation.

Comment: @kirma You should use `PossibleZeroQ`, with `Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"`. This post [Most efficient way to determine conclusively whether an algebraic number is zero](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18381/most-efficient-way-to-determine-conclusively-whether-an-algebraic-number-is-zero) discusses the issue.

Comment: @Artes I'm aware of `PossibleZeroQ` and `"ExactAlgebraics"`. :)

What I'd wish here would be a similar "knob" for functions like `Less`; apparently it isn't present directly. Something that'd pre-evaluate `Simplify` for all arguments of these comparison functions before performing them.

Comment: @Nasser regardless of its applicability to this question, that sort of comparison may be inherently unreliable. MATLAB and Fortran follow IEEE754, while *Mathematica* does not, so one cannot expect to obtain the same results from different systems.

Comment: @Oleksandr R. For elementary operations in machine arithmetic, Mathematica is almost certainly in compliance with IEEE754, for the simple reason that it only runs on compliant processors/OSs. The same is likely to hold for those function evaluations for which library code is used, since (I believe) many such libraries are in compliance. Not sure whether there is a compliance issue with some special functions insofar as I'm not sure the standard addresses that area in entirety...

Comment: @Oleksandr R. ...If you had in mind bignum arithmetic rather than machine precision, then Mathematica is certainly different from IEEE754. For purposes of zero comparison it is (far) less likely (than IEEE-based numeric comparison codes) to claim that mathematically equivalent numeric expressions are not equal...

Comment: @Oleksandr R. ... Of course there are other aspects of arithmetic besides zero testing, and IEEE standard for fixed precision bignums is not, at this time, quite attainable within Mathematica (the issue being, as you probably know, that various nondefault rounding modes are not supported). I am not sure to what extent it might be emulated-- [this](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6499298) will give an idea of how close I was able to come, but maybe others have better approaches.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau the main area of departure as I see it is the tolerance applied on the comparison operators and the fact that `Infinity` and `Indeterminate` behave differently to IEEE infs and NaNs. While disabling the tolerance is possible in our own routines, for users it's hard to know where it's applied internally, hence where and when an error (versus strict IEEE arithmetic) of up to 7 ULPs might be able to accumulate. In fact, knowing what is done with a library call or using (potentially mixed precision) bignum arithmetic is difficult in itself. By saying it is not fully IEEE-compliant

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I don't mean to criticize *Mathematica*'s approach to numerics on its own terms, but just to note that I don't think it's realistic to expect bit-for-bit reproducibility of non-trivial results obtained in dedicated numerics codes.

Comment: @Oleksandr R. Good point about the comparison operators. So conditionals based thereon will likely not behave identically to, say, Fortran library code. That said, I suspect that pretty much any math-related code depending on comparisons will be dealing with granularity issues-- I don't recall offhand whether IEEE has much to say about that. What I'm getting at is bit reproducibility of any one program by another is likely to be difficult. But yes, if "the other" is Mathematica, then the difficulty maybe does increase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses trick to redefine internal functions presented in [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8245258/2296803) by Leonid Shifrin.

```
(* Code run as an argument of WithFullySimplifiedComparisons tries
   harder to symbolically resolve equality and inequality tests. *)

ClearAll[WithFullySimplifiedComparisons];
WithFullySimplifiedComparisons =
  Module[
   {withReplacedFunctions, fullSimplifiedTest, testMappings, 
    splitInequality, wrapper},

   (* Runs code with functions in { old -> new, ... } mappings list
      executing new function in place of old, but old definitions
      working inside new implementations. *)

   SetAttributes[withReplacedFunctions, HoldRest];
   withReplacedFunctions[mappings_List, code_] :=
    Module[{outer = True},
     Internal`InheritedBlock[Evaluate@mappings[[All, 1]],
      (Unprotect[#1];
         #1[args___] :=
          Block[{outer = False}, #2[args]] /; outer;
         Protect[#1];) & @@@ mappings;
      code]];

   (* Returns a version of comparison function fun that attempts to
      simplify numeric comparisons in domain dom with FullSimplify. *)

   fullySimplifiedTest[fun_, dom_] :=
    Module[{test},
     test[] := True;
     test[_] := True;
     test[a_, b_, r___] :=
      With[{bn = FullSimplify[b]},
        If[fun[0, FullSimplify[bn - a]],
          test[bn, r], False, test[a, bn] && test[bn, r]]] /; 
       NumericQ[a] && NumericQ[b] && (a | b) \[Element] dom;
     test[a_, b_, r___] := fun[a, b] && test[b, r];
     test];

   (* Mappings for normal comparison functions. *)

   testMappings = 
    #1 -> fullySimplifiedTest[##] & @@@ 
     Join[{#, Complexes} & /@ {Equal, Unequal},
       {#, Reals} & /@ {Greater, GreaterEqual, Less, LessEqual}];

   (* Conversion function from Inequality to chain of simple tests. *)

   splitInequality[_] := True;
   splitInequality[a_, test_, b_, r___] := test[a, b] && splitInequality[b, r];

   (* Actual wrapper to be used.
      splitInequality uses new comparison functions. *)

   SetAttributes[wrapper, HoldFirst];
   wrapper[code_] :=
     withReplacedFunctions[testMappings,
       withReplacedFunctions[{Inequality -> splitInequality},
         code]];

   wrapper];
```

Now earlier problematic tests can run purely symbolically:

```
WithFullySimplifiedComparisons[
  x > y /. {x -> Sqrt[(2 - Sqrt[3])^2 + (-3 + 2*Sqrt[3])^2], y -> 4 - 2*Sqrt[3]}]
```

> False

Comment: Accepted as answer as it solves the example, and no other attempts appeared... I'm a bit suspicious of reliability of `withReplacedFunctions`, but it's an attempt better than nothing.