# Why the EuclideanDistance of these 2 exact points generates the warning N::meprec?

Tags: functions, precision-and-accuracy

The two points are:

```
pts = {{1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8]}, 
       {1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), -Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8]}};
EuclideanDistance @@ pts
```

> N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached
>   while evaluating 1/4 (-1-Sqrt[5])+1/4 (1+Sqrt[5]). >>

```
(* Sqrt[4 (5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8) + Abs[1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) + 1/4 (1 + Sqrt[5])]^2] *)
```

According to the document, `EuclideanDistance[u, v]` equals to `Norm[u - v]`, so it's not surprising that a `Norm` version generates the same warning and result:

```
Norm[Subtract @@ pts]
```

> N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached
>   while evaluating 1/4 (-1-Sqrt[5])+1/4 (1+Sqrt[5]). >>

```
(* Sqrt[4 (5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8) + Abs[1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) + 1/4 (1 + Sqrt[5])]^2] *)
```

The warning disappears if we choose `Sqrt`:

```
Sqrt[Total[(Subtract @@ pts)^2]]

(* Sqrt[4 (5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8) + (1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) + 1/4 (1 + Sqrt[5]))^2] *)
```

Why? Simply a bug?

Comment: No, not a bug. This is how Mathematica works. I think it is similar issue as this one http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31822/how-to-make-mathematica-try-harder-to-perform-symbolic-comparisons#comment99197_31822. If you do this: `$MinPrecision = $MachinePrecision;
$MaxPrecision = $MachinePrecision; EuclideanDistance @@ pts` the warning goes away. Mathematica needed more than 50 precision to decide on this one. That is all. You can also try `$MaxExtraPrecision = Infinity; EuclideanDistance @@ pts` but then you have to wait long time....

Comment: see See http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/MathematicsAndAlgorithms/MathematicsAndAlgorithms.pdf  page 20 for more discussion.

Comment: @Nasser I'm afraid that `$MaxExtraPrecision = Infinity;` won't work, at least it generates the warning `General::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.` in my computer 囧.

Comment: Yes, same thing on my computer also, kernel actually crashed and I got an error message from C++ library. I did not say this will work, I said to try it :)

Comment: @xzczd If numerics-based zero-testing of an expression (that is symbolically zero) fails to produce trustworthy result of zero or non-zero at some precision, it typically fails to do so at every level of precision. This is documented issue for `$MaxExtraPrecision`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Mathematica* produces this `Message` during evaluation of `Abs[1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) + 1/4 (1 + Sqrt[5])]`. It seemingly tries to calculate approximate value of this expression using `N` although the user does not ask for this. Note that

```
Simplify[Unevaluated@Abs[1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) + 1/4 (1 + Sqrt[5])]]
```

produces no error messages and gives correct result (`0`). Evaluation of `1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) + 1/4 (1 + Sqrt[5])` does not produce any messages. So the reason is that `Abs` has some internal code which evaluates numerically some exact but complicated expressions, and it is [showed](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Abs.html#17055592) in the "Possible issues" section on the Documentation page for `Abs`.

Comment: Oh… I should have check the document of `Abs`…

Comment: Also, you can attempt to redefine `Abs -> (Abs[FullSimplify[#]] &)` with a internals-overriding function such as `withReplacedFunctions` in [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31884/3056). Nonetheless the warning is just a warning and (mostly) harmless - worst it does is leaving the subexpression unevaluated.