# Ray tracing: Insufficient precision

Tags: vector, arbitrary-precision

I am writing a ray tracer to find the intersection point between a single ray and a cylinder.

```
intersectionPoint[pa_, va_, a_, u_, r_] := 
 Module[{p, L, t1, t2, k}, p = a + u*t;
 L = Solve[(p - pa - (va.(p - pa))*va).(p - 
 pa - (va.(p - pa))*va) == r^2, t];
 t1 = t /. L[[1]];
 t2 = t /. L[[2]];
 If[t1 < t2 && t1 >= 0, k = t1, k = t2];
 k];

 Q = {x, y, z};
 p1 = pa = {0, 0, 1};
 p2 = {0, 0, 10};
 va = (p2 - p1)/Norm[p2 - p1];
 a = {-6, -6, 0};
 u = {1, 1, -1};
 p = a + u*t;

 A[1] = ContourPlot3D[(Q - pa - (va.(Q - pa))*va).(Q - 
   pa - (va.(Q - pa))*va) == 25, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 
10}, {z, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5]];

A[2] = ParametricPlot3D[p, {t, 0, k}];
(*Show[A[1],A[2]]*)

 k = intersectionPoint[pa, va, a, u, 5]

 A[3] = Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.01], Point[a + u*k]}];

  Show[A[1], A[2], A[3]]
```

The program was working fine until I decided to find the unit normal vector of the intersection point:

```
UnitNormal[Q_, pa_, va_] := Module[{B, n},
 B = pa + (va.(Q - pa))*va;
 n = Normalize[Q - B];
n];
```

and when I tried to test an example -- it failed

```
UnitNormal[a + u*k, pa, va]
```

> N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating 1/2 (12-5 Sqrt[2])+1/2 (-12+5 Sqrt[2]). >>

And this was posted as an output:
[image]

As you can see in the picture above, while *Mathematica* is representing the last fraction numerator as $\frac{1}{2}(12-5\sqrt2)+\frac{1}{2}(-12+5\sqrt2)$ it does not simplify it to `0`. Why is this happening and is there a solution for fixing this problem?

Comment: First of all, you probably don't want to use symbolic values on a ray tracer. (Also, you don't want to run `Solve` on every `intersectionPoint` invocation!) It'll slow your computation horrendously. Also, you may want to take a look at: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31822/3056

Comment: You have encountered an exact numeric expression that Mathematica thinks might be zero, but is not certain. hence the message. As for what to do about that, presumably going to approximate values e.g. via `NSolve` will improve on the situation. If you want exact values for whatever reason you might avoid the zero-or-not issue by use of `Together`. Maybe.