# Faster way to test if an expression equals zero

Tags: algorithm, expression-test

I want to test if expressions (mix of variables, functions and numbers) are zero valued, as fast as possible, and `PossibleZeroQ` is sometimes very slow. One solution I found was to substitute the variables for random reals and test if the value of the substituted expression is less than, say, $0.0001$.

It works good, but maybe there are other solutions out there.

I know it can cause some wrong answers, but what is most important is the speed, since I can check the false positive later with `PossibleZeroQ`.

Can you think of an algorithm that can perform fast zero value tests in detriment of some loss of accuracy?

Edit:

I'll post my algorithm here:

```
TestZeroValuedExpression[expression_,symbolslist_]:=Module[{numericvalue},
Quiet[TimeConstrained[If[Check[
    numericvalue=N[Expand[expression/.Table[symbolslist[[i]]->RandomReal[{1,2}],{i,Length[symbolslist]}]]];
,False]=!=False,
    If[Abs[numericvalue]>0.00001,False,PossibleZeroQ[expression]],
    PossibleZeroQ[expression]
],3,False]]
];
```

Comment: It would be constructive if you demonstrated expressions making `PossibleZeroQ` work very slowly. Look e.g. here [Most efficient way to determine conclusively whether an algebraic number is zero](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18381/most-efficient-way-to-determine-conclusively-whether-an-algebraic-number-is-zero/18390#18390).  `PossibleZeroQ` won all those tests.

Comment: Maybe I was not very clear, but I want to test a lot of expressions per second, the more, the better. With the algorithm I suggested, I test about 300 expressions per second. With PossibleZeroQ, this drops to about 10 per second (using TimeConstrained for 0.5 seconds, otherwise this gets even worse, or just freezes).

Comment: Perhaps you should try something like combinations of `N` and `Chop[ N@expr_, delta]`  e.g. `test[expr_, a_] := Chop[ N[expr /. x :> RandomReal[{-a, a}]], a]`

Comment: I'll test that suggestion. Thanks

Comment: If you have say rational functions with sign changes and coefficients modestly large, and if your substituted numbers are machine doubles so precision tracking is not done, then cancellation error could give you false negatives.

Comment: could you had the expressions (at least a few hundred) somewhere externally. that would help to do some testing on our own and not just guessing.

Comment: Daniel, could you explain better? How could I avoid false negatives?

Answer (score 1):

Another improved version

```
TestConstantValuedExpression[expression_,zerovaluetest_]:=Module[{randomvaluestestresult,expressionrandomvalue,previousexpressionrandomvalue,symbolreplacementlist,extremesdifferencetestvalue},
randomvaluestestresult=True;
previousexpressionrandomvalue=False;
Quiet[
    Do[
        Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision=Infinity},
                symbolreplacementlist={_->False};
                TimeConstrained[
                    While[!FreeQ[$Assumptions/.symbolreplacementlist,False],symbolreplacementlist=Table[symbolslist[[dvi]]->RandomChoice[{-1,1}]*10^Round[RandomVariate[StudentTDistribution[2]]],{dvi,Length[symbolslist]}]]
            ,0.2,nskippedsymbolreplacementlists++;Continue[]];
            TimeConstrained[
                expressionrandomvalue=Check[N[expression/.symbolreplacementlist],Continue[]];
            ,0.2,nskippedexpressionrandomvalues++;Continue[]];
        ];
        If[previousexpressionrandomvalue=!=False,
            If[Chop[expressionrandomvalue-previousexpressionrandomvalue,10^-4]=!=0,randomvaluestestresult=False;Break[],previousexpressionrandomvalue=expressionrandomvalue];
        ,previousexpressionrandomvalue=expressionrandomvalue];
    ,{60}];
    If[randomvaluestestresult,
        extremesdifferencetestvalue=Chop[TimeConstrained[Minimize[{expression,$Assumptions},symbolslist][[1]],60,0]-TimeConstrained[Maximize[{expression,$Assumptions},symbolslist][[1]],60,0],10^-4];
        If[extremesdifferencetestvalue===0||extremesdifferencetestvalue==={0,0},
            If[zerovaluetest,TimeConstrained[PossibleZeroQ[FullSimplify[expression]],360,False],True]
        ,False]
    ,False]
]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, posting my version here. It has 0.1 seconds to test, otherwise returns false. I am assuming that if it takes longer than that, then the expression being tested is too complex (for my problem) and is not useful.

```
TestZeroValuedExpression[expression_,symbolslist_]:=Module[{expressionrandomvalue},
    Quiet[TimeConstrained[If[Check[
        expressionrandomvalue=Chop[N[expression/.Table[symbolslist[[i]]->RandomInteger[{-3,3}],{i,Length[symbolslist]}]]];
    ,False]=!=False,
        If[expressionrandomvalue!=0,False,PossibleZeroQ[expression]],
        PossibleZeroQ[expression]
    ],0.1,False]]
];
```