# Error about limit MaxExtraPrecision

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

After my evaluations I have an error:
`N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision=50. reached while evaluating ...`
`General::stop: Futher output of N::mecprec will be supressed during this calculation.`

As as I might guess, the problem is that I am evaluating very big numbers, and the precision limit is ended. 
But what that means for my number: how big will be the suppression?
Can I do something to reduce this error?
If the suppression is not very big (for example only from the 50th decimal number),
how can I store this value, to have possibility to use them in `Reduce` function, because when I want to use this value I have an error:
`Unable to decide whether numeric quantity ... is equal to zero. Assuming it is.` How can I make to NOT assuming it is zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the problem child inside of `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000},...]`.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps. But with `Reduce` function I have still the same problem, because I have error that: `Unable to decide whether numeric quantity ... is equal to zero. Assuming it is.` How can I make to NOT assuming it is zero?

Comment: @Ziva: Would need more details on what you're doing and exact contents of error. Perhaps update your OP. Also, see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18381/most-efficient-way-to-determine-conclusively-whether-an-algebraic-number-is-zero` for related information.