# Simplifying a complicated expression (with no variables)

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to obtain some exact analytical results without resorting to numerical approximations, and I ended up with a pretty huge expression that Mathematica is really struggling with. It has no variables, no crazy things like 17th degree polynomials etc. but Mathematica still can't `FullSimplify` it.

I uploaded it [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw/qaPBQ2nw) so you can just `Import` it and see. You can check numerically that it's just a real expression, it gives `-0.075865`.

I have tried a few methods that worked for me before — expanding it in different ways or trying `FullSimplify` with a very short `TimeConstraint` to obtain even a slightly simplified form. However, nothing works and Mathematica keeps running out of memory or the kernel simply quits while evaluating the expression (Mathematica 10.3, OS X).

Are there any tricks or methods to obtain a simplified expression for complicated analytical results like that? What else can I try?

Comment: Do you have any steps before, where you might simplify?

Comment: @Fabian Not really. The expression comes from the normalized eigenvectors of a (fully simplified) matrix. It applies a very simple function (2nd degree polynomial) to their coefficients, and simplifying the eigenvectors themselves is basically equivalent to simplifying this. I also get no results there.

Comment: I don't think `FullSimplify` can handle it because the way it operates.

Comment: What do you mean by "simplify"?  The final numerical value is the "simplification" of that enormous term.  Why isn't `N[ ]` sufficient?  In your terminology, what would be the "simplification" of $3 + 5$?

Comment: You probably have to to it by hand. So pick terms and simplify them individually, step by step.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think he means to shorten the expression. So that the simplified expression is something like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gq70k.png This will probably simplify further and further, so he can put the exact number in a paper.

Answer (score 3):

You can 
 use

```
RootApproximant[N[val, 10000], 20]
```

> (14700 - 12000 Sqrt[2])/29929

So

```
newval=(14700 - 12000 Sqrt[2])/29929;
```

To test it:

```
N[newval, 100000] - N[val, 100000]
```

> 0.*10^-100001

but strangely:

```
N[newval - val]
```

> 1.00697*10^-13

Comment: the last result is not strange. It is doing a machine precision evaluation of that whole mess, so unlikely to be exact zero even if your `newval` is the exact correct expression.

Comment: maybe want to look at this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18381/2079